# Docker - Spring boot app - Hello World on Windows

Tags: windows, maven, docker, spring-boot

I followed this example: http://containertutorials.com/docker-compose/spring-boot-app.html
but when I run Maven (Windows) at the end I got this error:

```
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.DockerException: ADD failed: stat /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder201282403/gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar: no such file or directory
```

I thinks I have to change the Dockerfile here, but how?

```
VOLUME /tmp
ADD gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar app.jar
```

Any suggest?
Thanks

Comment: i don't know if it helps, but from what I know of docker, it's not supposed to work with windows, unless if you use a VM. And in your example it's from Linux. Maybe this is the root cause.

Comment: It has worked on Windows with the VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the **gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar** next to your docker file. The error indicates that the jar is missing. Make sure when compiling that the jar is being created inside the ${project.build.directory} and that it has the same name as specified in the Dockerfile: gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar

Comment: Yes it was my error. I needed to change the name 
ADD <name> app.jar

Comment: And how did you change it?